# Slideout Menu - Hiding Horizontal Scrollbar Whilst in Transition

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design, overflow

I'm trying to create a slideout responsive menu and it's workling fairly well (in Chrome, at least).

I have run into one problem though. Basically, when you click the menu button the menu will slide out, the body will move to the right (maintaining it's width) and it looks great. The problem occurs when you're sliding back out - the jQuery removes the class that hides the horizontal scrollbar and it causes that scrollbar to flash while the menu is sliding back out of the screen.

The class/CSS that hides the scrollbar looks like this:

```
.mob-menu-open {
    margin-left: 260px;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
```

And this bit of jQuery removes the class:

```
$('body').toggleClass('mob-menu-open');
```

I've set up a JSFiddle to demonstrate the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/tgxgT/

I'm attempting to create something that can be reused so I don't want to use the wrapper div as that won't always be present. I have thought of one problem which would be to use jQuery to do the animations and removing the class after completion with a callback but if possible  I'd prefer to stick just to CSS. If it's not do-able then I'll go down the jQuery route.

Is there any way I can solve this little problem?

Any creative ideas would be really welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you want to play around with the body tag to much.

I would set the wrapper to `#wrapper { overflow: hidden; }` and then place all the content
that moves inside a div with a specified width e.g. `.content {width: 100%;}` and just move the .content div.

I played around with your jsFiddle for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/EfG2m/
There I placed the top bar and the menu inside the content because then they move with the div. If you want them to be fixed to the top place them outside and animate them separately.

I hope this is more or less clear…